# R: Parse character vector into data frame

Tags: r, parsing, dataframe

I used readlines() to import a character vector from one file that has almost 200 rows like this each.
The first column of the first row is "H"
The first column of the second row is "R"
The first column of the third row is "S"

I want to parse the rows into data frames. dfH , dfR and dfS  The first column of each row deterimines which df that row belongs in.

Once I can get rid of the \ from the data its just csv with each row in its own set of quotes.

The column names and data types of each data frame are fixed and known

```
[1] "\"H\",\"USA\",\"AQU\",\"20080301\",\"9\",\"D\",\"Antique\""

[2] "\"R\",\"1\",\"TB\",\"ALW\",\"S\",\" \",\"4U\",\" \",\"47000\",\"0\",\"47000\",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\" \",\"800\",\"F\",\"D\",\"N\",\"8\",\" \",\" \",\" \",\"12:30PM\",\"12:58PM\",\"1230\",\" \",\"Alw 47000N1X\",\"Fast\",\"\",\"19\",\"76\",\" \",\"\",\"\",\"44\",\"140.84\",\"2341\",\"4765\",\"11372\",\"0\",\"0\",\" \",\"\",\"217217\",\"Good\",\"Clear\",\"\",\"\",\"Y\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

[3] "\"S\",\"1\",\"000007168997TB\",\"Oak\",\"20040411\",\"NY\",\"TB\""
```

Comment: You might be better-off using `read.csv` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want each string starting with H to be a row in `dfH`, each string starting with R to be a row in `dfR`, and each string starting with `S` to be a row in `dfS`. Let's start by doubling your example data so there will be two rows in each of these three resulting data frames:

```
dat = rep(c("\"H\",\"USA\",\"AQU\",\"20080301\",\"9\",\"D\",\"Antique\"", "\"R\",\"1\",\"TB\",\"ALW\",\"S\",\" \",\"4U\",\" \",\"47000\",\"0\",\"47000\",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\" \",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\" \",\"800\",\"F\",\"D\",\"N\",\"8\",\" \",\" \",\" \",\"12:30PM\",\"12:58PM\",\"1230\",\" \",\"Alw 47000N1X\",\"Fast\",\"\",\"19\",\"76\",\" \",\"\",\"\",\"44\",\"140.84\",\"2341\",\"4765\",\"11372\",\"0\",\"0\",\" \",\"\",\"217217\",\"Good\",\"Clear\",\"\",\"\",\"Y\"", "\"S\",\"1\",\"000007168997TB\",\"Oak\",\"20040411\",\"NY\",\"TB\""), 2)
```

Now we can apply `read.csv` to convert each string value into a data frame and `rbind` to build your three data frames:

```
dfs <- lapply(dat, function(x) read.csv(text=x, header=F))
first.char <- unlist(lapply(dfs, `[`, 1, 1))
dfH <- do.call(rbind, dfs[first.char == "H"])
dfR <- do.call(rbind, dfs[first.char == "R"])
dfS <- do.call(rbind, dfs[first.char == "S"])
dfH
#   V1  V2  V3       V4 V5 V6      V7
# 1  H USA AQU 20080301  9  D Antique
# 2  H USA AQU 20080301  9  D Antique
```

Comment: It works on  the sample data that I provided but I can't get it to work on the full data set. https://s3.amazonaws.com/ACEO/AQU20080327.chart